# How to recenter a geolocation google common map in views after an ajax boundary filter execution?

Tags: 8, views, ajax, google-maps

On Drupal 8.97 with all updated modules, I have a View that uses a Geolocation Google Common Map as an attachment. The map acts a boundary filter, but after the filter executes `Drupal.ajax(ajaxSettings).execute()` via `/modules/contrib/geolocation/modules/geolocation_google_maps/js/geolocation-common-map-google.js`, I am unable to re-center the map to ANY coordinates, including the user's location.

Before the ajax call, `map.getCenter()` works, and so does manually inputting coordinates, like `map.getCenter({ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 })`, but afterwards, no dice. The custom re-center buttons I created still register clicks, and if console.log the map object afterwards, I can't see any changes to the map object...and indeed some of my other custom map controls (like zoom in and out) still work after the ajax execution. I'm baffled.

I have looked at the ajaxSettings object too, and have attempted to change some of those center related properties before executing the `Drupal.ajax(ajaxSettings).execute()` command as above, but I still can't get the map center to change (though I don't quite know if I'm looking at the right properties...there's hundreds of them). The map can still be panned around with a mouse of course, but I ultimately would like for users to be able to re-center to their location...and I would like to programmatically recenter and execute a search using the center of city locations without having to reload the page, so it's kind of critical that I get this sorted.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe related [Change center on a map](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation/issues/3046988)

Comment: There is already a "built in" feature for re-centering the map to the client location...and that doesn't work either...before or after the ajax call: `/modules/contrib/geolocation/modules/geolocation_google_maps/js/MapFeature/geolocation-control-recenter.js`